# finding the present value using C++

Tags: c++

assignment at school asks me to find the present value using double, and void. i was able to write my code up to a certain degree but the result is not what i was expecting.. i ended up separating the present value into different section so at the end i'd multiply the amount given with the rest.. any tips on how to make the code actually work the way its supposed to?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double payment,year_term, interest;
    double sum;
    double Power;
    double presentv;
    double present;

    cout << "Hello, how are you doing?" << endl;
    cout << "Please insert a payment amount" << endl;
    cin  >> payment;
    cout << " amount inserted: " << payment << endl;
    cout << "Enter number of years" << endl;
    cin  >> year_term;
    cout << " number of years: " << year_term << endl;
    cout << "Enter interest rate" << endl;
    cin  >> interest;
    cout << " the interest is: " << interest << "%" << endl;

    Presentv = ((1 - (pow((1 + interest),year_term))))/interest;
    cout << " the value: " << Presentv << endl;
    presentva = payment * Presentv;
    cout << " the present value is: " << presentva << endl;
}
```

Comment: Be precise about your problem ... what is the expected output and actual output.

Comment: This can't compile as is. For a start, neither `Presentv` nor `presentva` exist.

Comment: What does present value mean? and why use double and void?

Comment: @Paul, PV is a financial term, simplistically the assumed *present* value of some amount of cash to be received in the future (discounted because you're not getting interest on it between now and then). Apologies, my wife is a CA :-)